# How to select a nested tag from a XML with querySelector? (querySelector, nested tags)

Tags: javascript, xml, queryselector

For a little side-project I am fetching data from rss-feeds and need to select an image url in order to render the cover of a podcast in my application.

I am selecting the mp3, title and author in the fetched XML like this, which works fine.

```
const items = feed.querySelectorAll('item');
const feedItems = [...items].slice(0, 1).map((el) => ({
      mp3: el.querySelector('enclosure').getAttribute('url'),
      title: el.querySelector('title').innerHTML,
      author: el.querySelector('author').innerHTML,
    }));
```

The image url is nested in the XML though and I am having troubles to select it with querySelector.

```
<image>
<link>https://erklaermir.simplecast.com</link>
<title>Erklär mir die Welt</title>
<url>https://image.simplecastcdn.com/images/8991e97a-2827-4ade-a709-e50208868f3f/59e8ae3d-526c-435b-8ab8-0b2da0fa12ba/3000x3000/1521828793artwork.jpg?aid=rss_feed</url>
</image>
```

The link to the complete feed. https://feeds.feedburner.com/erklaermir

Does somebody know how I can select the nested url-tag in this XML?

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<url>` element is an element (like `<link>` and `<title>`) not an attribute (you have no attributes in your XML).

You get data from it the same way as you get data from the other elements.

… except you should be using `textContent` for all of them since you want the strings as strings not as serialised HTML (with any special characters potentially encoded as character references).

You don't have an `<enclosure>` element at all, so I've no idea what `el.querySelector('enclosure')` is supposed to be doing.

```
el.querySelector('url').textContent
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. :) Sorry maybe it is more clear with the complete rss feed, I edited the question and included the url from the entire feed.

Comment: What is it about this complete answer that makes you think your question was unclear?

Comment: Thank you for the textContent input. Need to fix that. Because I struggle to specify which url element in the XML, which would be the one in the image element.

Comment: Again, this answer covers that. You do the same thing you did for the other elements.

Comment: I am sorry just noticed my question is confusing, because I with mp3: el.querySelector('enclosure').getAttribute('url') I am selecting a url attribute. The element I am trying to select is the one within the image tag, though. It has nothing to do with the url attribute.